# Redireccionar a un Puerto en Dominio

Tags: php, sql

Que tal amigos mi pregunta es tengo un portal web con direccion ejemplo: www.miportal.com pero necesito acceder a un sistema pero que este se ingrese por el puerto 81 sistemaxy.miportal.com:81 como puedo hacer eso? De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: revisa esta liga: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589368/how-to-redirect-different-sub-domain-requests-to-different-port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo donde esta tu sitio puedes configurar el puerto de ingreso.

Si tienes `VPS` o servidor dedicado puedes configurar el archivo vhosts para indicar que las peticiones solo se acceden por el `puerto 81`. Por ejemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Si es un servidor compartido puedes poner una regla con htaccess. Por ejemplo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.midominio.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:2222%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

127.0.0.1 es la dirección de tu servidor.